# jmeter pass in Variable in Request from File

Tags: variables, jmeter

I try to start a jmeter with full soap-requests in a csv file. Inside the request I have a jemeter-Variable.
In jmeter-meter a Userdefined Variable is defined (e.g. authkey=1234567)
in csv-file is the soap-request:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <Request AuthKey="${Authkey}}">
            <Element1>...</Element1>
        </Request>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Body date in jmeter is read from file with Variable ${REQUEST}, but the "Authkey" is not set in Request and it fails...
I tried with the following Variable-Type "${__V{Authkey}}", "${__evalVar{Authkey}}", but no success. Is it possible to pass through a Variable-name from csv inputfile?

Comment: Try `${__V(Authkey)}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your variable from the CSV Data Set Config into [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) function, this way JMeter will resolve all JMeter Functions or Variables in you XML file to their respective values

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)